# Child Theme not overriding Parent CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, parent-child

I've created a child theme of the Renovation theme. In the child's theme folder I have a "style.css" and a "functions.php" file. My style.css looks like this:

```
/*
Theme Name: Renovation Child
Theme URI: http://renovation.thememove.com/
Author: ThemeMove
Author URI: http://thememove.com/
Version: 2.0.4
Template: tm-renovation
*/

/*
 * @charset "UTF-8";
*/

.vc_custom_1438936121266 {
    margin-bottom: 70px!important;
    padding-top: 65px!important;
    padding-bottom: 35px!important;
}
```

My functions.php looks like this:

```
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION

if ( !function_exists( 'renovation_enqueue_scripts' ) ):
    function renovation_enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'renovation-child-style', trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css' );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'renovation_enqueue_scripts' );

// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
```

Unsing the inspector I see that the parent css is being loaded first and it looks like this:

```
.vc_custom_1438936121266 {
    margin-bottom: 70px!important;
    padding-top: 30px!important;
    padding-bottom: 35px!important;
}
```

My CSS is being loaded after the parent CSS and it looks like this, except it's all crossed out:

```
.vc_custom_1438936121266 {
    margin-bottom: 70px!important;
    padding-top: 65px!important;           <-- MY CHANGE
    padding-bottom: 35px!important;
}
```

I've read alot of threads about specificity, and I noticed that my css and the parent css are identical, except for the "padding-top" change I made. Since the child is loaded last, I expected my css to take precedence, but it's not. My css is crossed out in the inspector and the parent is being used.

This doesn't seem right to me, and I was hoping that someone could clarify my understanding of the parent/child relationship and help me fix this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Are they loaded in the correct order in the head of the page? Because it's true that the latest css style is applied

Comment: As far as I can tell they are loaded in the correct order, with my css being loaded last.

Answer (score 0):

if you are only going to override one element and not apply this to multiple it might be best to use an id instead of a class. The id is always overwrites a class.